# Pointer as parameter in Linux kernel code

Tags: c, pointers

Recently, I have read the linux kernel code to see how the code looks like. I understands only the basic of pointers.
So, i came across this function declaration:-

```
kernel_write(struct file *file, const void *buf, size_t count,loff_t *pos)
```

What does **struct file *file** imply?
Based on my understanding, **struct file *file** means that you pass the pointer that points to the memory blocks that contains multiple **file** structs?  
Here is a diagram to visualize my understanding :-

[image: diagram]


Is my understanding accurate or i am actually misguided?

Comment: Any basic learning resource will cover this. If you only understand the basics of pointers then I'd steer away from the kernel for a while ;-)

Comment: A pointer can point to exactly one item or an array of items.  But you need to know how many.  so if there is a count or size parameter then it is an array but if there is not then it must just be one.  the `buf` parameter has a corresponding `count` parameter so it will be an array, but the `file` parameter does not so it isn't.  The reason `file` is a pointer is because passing an entire structure on the stack uses a lot of memory if the structure is big so passing a pointer to the structure is better.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks for the explanation. Another knowledge added. :D

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not correct. In this context, that pointer points to exactly one `struct file`. Advancing it and trying to read a second one would be Undefined Behavior, and that's especially bad when it happens in the kernel.

Comment: Thanks..I think i have the wrong context here...i am not asking about the kernel but the pointer concept which is my bad. So in c pointer context, is my understanding valid?

Comment: @HarithIkhwan No. Even outside of the kernel, not every pointer is guaranteed to point to multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons to use a pointer as a parameter.

1. The pointer points to an array of items.  You need to know how many items so there must be a count or size parameter to indicate how big the array is.  The `buf` parameter is an array and the `count` parameter indicates how big it is.
2. The pointer is used to avoid copying a huge structure via the stack.  Functions receive a copy of the item passed to them.  If the structure is really big then copying the entire structure is a bad idea but passing a pointer is a much smaller thing so it is a better idea.
3. The pointer is used to allow the function to modify the value passed to it.  Functions receive a copy of the item passed to them.  So modifying the parameter only modifies the copy and not the original.  If a pointer is passed then you can't modify where the pointer points but you can modify what the pointer points at.

In the particular example you show I can't tell if they pass a pointer to `file` because they need to modify the contents of the structure (#3) or because the structure is really big and they are worried about how much stack space the copy will take up (#2).  But it is almost certainly NOT an array (#1) because there is no size or count parameter to say how big the array is (which means the pointer can only point at one structure).

If you want some examples of each case let me know.